# I get an error saying, "exit status 1 expected initializer before 'void'."

Tags: arduino-mega, c++, code-review, error

I will be wiring a switch to the Arduino that controls the voltage. When the I turn the switch it can adjust the voltage from 0 to 5. The overall task is to print the output voltage. The print is to be a multiplication table of the voltage.

I created this code:

```
void setup()

void loop(){
  
  int (n,i,j,result);
 
  printf("enter N Value");

  scanf ("%d", &n);

  for (i=1; i<=n; i++);

  {
    for (j=1; j<=n;j++);

    {
      result= (i*j);

      printf("%d", result);

    }
    printf("\n");

  }
  return 0;

}
```

But i get the error exit status 1
expected initializer before 'void' when I try to verify it. what does it mean. How do you fix it?

Comment: Your `setup()` function has no body.

Comment: @Majenko what do you recommend for the set up? I though it could run off the loop

Comment: If you don't need any setup code then give it an empty body.

Comment: @Majenko im not sure if anything needs to go in the setup. this is my second day of trying this, that's why im asking for assistance.  What do you recommend for ?

Comment: I think you should start by learning basic c syntax.

Comment: @Majenko well I am trying to learn at the moment. But that doesn't help me get this working.

Answer (score 3):

Functions must have a body. So instead of:

```
void setup()
```

You need:

```
void setup()
  {
  // do nothing
  }
```

---

You have other issues, for example this is not C++:

```
  int (n,i,j,result);
```

That should be:

```
  int n,i,j,result;
```

Also you are returning 0, when void functions don't return a value.

Also, here:

```
  printf("enter N Value");

  scanf ("%d", &n);
```

Where is this value coming from? There isn't a keyboard on the Arduino.

See: [scanf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)

> The C library function int scanf(const char *format, ...) reads formatted input from stdin.

The Arduino is a microprocessor. It doesn't have stdin.

Comment: Nick, Im under the impression that most of my issues remain in the fact that i have nothing in the setup body. that's why im getting errors like n, i, and j was not declared in this scope. How do you recommend I address this?

Comment: No, they are two different issues. I showed in my first paragraph how to fix setup.

Comment: with the corrections you gave me the code was verified. Im going to have to work on it doing what i need.   Also you asked we i got these, I pulled them from other forums and tried to piece together something. I know its not proper but its the second day for me learning this.

Comment: OK, you are progressing. :) You might want to read up on **Serial** because that lets you work with the Serial Monitor (something you can activate in the IDE), and (using the USB interface) you could indeed show text, and receive text. However **printf** and **scanf** are not the exact functions you need for that.

Comment: Great, thank you so much. I will look into them now.